# What mechanism allows the unprivileged graphical session to control the backlight device?

Tags: linux, permissions, gnome, backlight

Wayland (or unprivileged Xorg) is able to access DRM and input devices by fd-passing from `systemd-logind` or equivalent.  I can see these devices  (for the first seat) in `loginctl seat-status seat0`.

However I do not see a backlight device (`/sys/class/backlight/*/`) in this list of devices.

Additionally, while GNOME is able to control my backlight, my user has not been granted backlight permission through the sysfs file owner/group or ACL:

> `$ ls -ld /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight`
>   `lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 May 24 17:12 /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight`

```
$ cd /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
$ $ ls -l
total 0
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 4096 May 27 22:09 actual_brightness
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4096 May 27 22:17 bl_power
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4096 May 27 22:17 brightness
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 May 27 22:09 device -> ../../card0-eDP-1
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 4096 May 27 22:17 max_brightness
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    0 May 27 22:09 power
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 May 24 17:12 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../class/backlight
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 4096 May 27 22:17 type
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4096 May 27 22:17 uevent
$ getfacl bl_power brightness
# file: bl_power
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--

# file: brightness
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

What mechanism are the unprivileged processes in my GNOME session using, to control the backlight despite not being `root`?

EDITED TO ADD: the device `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1` is shown in `loginctl seat-status`, and this is the parent device of the backlight device.

I am using gnome-shell `3.28.2-1.fc28` with Wayland.  systemd is version `238-8.git0e0aa59.fc28`.

Comment: Probably ConsoleKit.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams no. ConsoleKit is not running, `ps -ax|grep -i console` shows nothing. AIUI systemd-logind replaces its functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backlight is set by `gsd-backlight-helper`, a `gnome-settings-daemon` helper which runs as root, thanks to a PolicyKit setting allowing the active user to do so. `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.policy` contains the following:

```
[...]
<action id="org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.backlight-helper">
  [...]
  <defaults>
    <allow_any>no</allow_any>
    <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
    <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
  </defaults>
[...]
```